# Implement binary search subroutine but no outcome

Tags: python, function, search, indexing

Details of the algorithm:

Given an array A of n elements with sorted values `A[0] ≤ A[1] ≤ ... ≤ A[n−1]`, and target value x, the following subroutine uses binary search to find the index of x in A.

Here is the code I wrote:

```py
def Binarysearch(A, x): 
    L = 0 
    R = len(A)-1 
    M = (L + R)//2 
    while L<=R: 
        if A[M] < x: 
            L = M+1 
        elif A[M] > x: 
            R = M-1 
        else: 
            return M 
    
    return None
```

PROBLEM:
By writing the following lines I get no outcome:

```py
list = [2,3,4,5,12,15,76]
Binarysearch(list, 3)
```

I would like to understand what is the problem.
I noticed that if I substitute after the else condition: return M with print(M) I get an infinite sequence of 1.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use the return value of the function value and print it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the interactive online tools - eg.  `http://www.pythontutor.com/`  - if you run through your code, it's easier to see where it went wrong.

Comment: Aside: don't name your variables `list`; it will lead to confusing problems when you try to use the `list` builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
M = (L + R)//2
```

Needs to be inside the loop. Otherwise, M is never updated, and you go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

As earlier post from @BrianMcCutchon pointed out, the flaw in the code and working solution.  You prob. have good grasp on the problem now.

I've just offered the `same` solution with more descriptive variable names here for your reference.

```py
def binary_iterative(A, target):
    ''' 
    Return the index of the target, or None if not found.

    The array A is in sorted order, and assumed each num. is unique.
    ''' 

    left, right = 0, len(A) - 1

    while left <= right:

        middle_idx = (left + right) // 2
        middle_num = A[middle_idx]

        if middle_num == target:
            return middle_idx
        
        elif middle_num < target:
            left = middle_idx + 1
            
        elif middle_num > target:
            right = middle_idx - 1
            
    return None



if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 20, 22]
    target = 5
    print(binary_iterative(nums, target))
```